# PHP System cleanup programs best practices to run program (script) but prevent unauthorized execution

Tags: php, security, schedule

want to ask if someone could recommend best practices for scenario when you would need to run PHP programs (scripts) daily to clean-up / archive data (in general) so the program may be executed automatically every night but in a way that it can check if execution is authorized (scheduled) and would not run if some user would figure out the program url.

Would you go with program that has GET parameter where you would pass secure token? Or is there any better way how to run scheduled scripts safely?

Thank you for any comments.

Comment: why not set up cron jobs if you have access to the installation server. Or do you need external data to run your script?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are on the right track i guess. You can do many things to protect cronjobs. Your suggestion to create a security token would be a great start. Personally i do the following things for cronjobs:

- Security token
- Only accessible by shell (with php code)
- Limit access by .htaccess
- Access for one ip only (server)

So far, never had any problems in 10 years.

Comment: No problem! Please accept the answer if ok. Thank you